# SwiftSocket: Can't send more than one TCP message

Tags: ios, swift, tcp, network-programming

I'm using [SwiftSocket](https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket) to send TCP messages from my iPad to a local device.

First message is received correctly but when I try to send another one, I get a `connectionTimeout` error.

Any idea?

Swift 3 code:

```
func sendMessage(_ message: String) {
    self.client = TCPClient(address: "192.168.0.16", port: 7777)

    switch self.client.connect(timeout: 1) {
    case .success:
        switch self.client.send(string: "\(message)\n") {
        case .success:
            print("success")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Sending error: \(error)")
        }

    case .failure(let error):
        print("Connection error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Code in CLI to listen to messages:

```
nc -l 192.168.0.16 7777
```

Comment: With socket communication, the socket usually stays open and you send multiple messages down it. I'm guessing the other end is still listening on the first connection you created. I think you want to pull the `connect` method out of here and store the open connection in a property. Otherwise, you need to disconnect each time, which isn't very efficient.

Comment: @DaveWeston How come I didn't think of this? That fixed my issue, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Skoua Hey! Im facing the same problem, do you want to share you solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this class

```
class SocketManager:  NSObject, StreamDelegate  {

     var serverAddress: CFString
     let serverPort: UInt32 = 6000

     private var inputStream: InputStream!
     private var outputStream: OutputStream!
     private var connecting:Bool

     init(ip:String) {
         serverAddress = ip as CFString
         connecting = false

         super.init()

         connect()
    }

    func disconect(){
       outputStream.close()
       inputStream.close()

   }
   func connect() {
       connecting = true

       while connecting {
          print("connecting...")

          var readStream:  Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
          var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?

          CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(nil, self.serverAddress, self.serverPort, &readStream, &writeStream)


          inputStream = readStream!.takeRetainedValue()
          outputStream = writeStream!.takeRetainedValue()

          inputStream.delegate = self
          outputStream.delegate = self

          inputStream.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
          outputStream.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)

          inputStream.open()
          outputStream.open()


         connecting = false
      }
    }


    public func sendMsg(msg : String){

       let data = msg.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
       // Write to output stream:
       _ = data.withUnsafeBytes { outputStream.write($0, maxLength: data.count) }
    }
    public func Receive(){
       let bufferSize = 81600
       var buffer = Array<UInt8>(repeating: 0, count: bufferSize)

       let bytesRead = inputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)
       if bytesRead >= 0 {
         let output = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: bytesRead, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
         DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            GlobalFunction.GVsharedInstance.Parser(msg: output as! String)
         }
      }
   }
}
```